# Unsupported method: AndroidProject.getVariantNames()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Клонировал проект андроид приложения с гитхаба. И получил следующее:

> ERROR: Unsupported method: AndroidProject.getVariantNames(). The
>   version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method. To
>   resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of
>   Gradle you connect to. Alternatively, you can ignore this exception
>   and read other information from the model.

Comment: здесь имеется в виду что вы скачали проект который был создан на версии градла ниже/выше того что у вас в студии, попробуйте понизить/повысить версию градла, должно помочь

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko спасибо, помогло